# MCCB breaking point

Tags: protection, circuit-protection

I am using MCCB rated for 16A. I wanted  to test weather its working or not. I am applying current 32A~38A the circuit breaker wont trip. 
[Datasheet refer here](http://in.element14.com/eaton-moeller/plsm-c32-3-mw/circuit-breaker-32a-3pole/dp/1085699)

Can someone tell it really faulted Circuit breaker or not

Answer (score 3):

Follow the link you inserted above and get the 'technical data sheet'. Look up the trip characteristics of the exact part number and trip characteristic you have to see how long it should take to trip at a given over-current.

It's not unusual for a breaker to take many seconds to trip even with a large overload. With a moderate overload it may take minutes or never trip.

[image]

Don't forget to factor in the ambient temperature- if the temperature is colder or hotter than the 30°C reference temperature the breaker will take more or less time at a given over-current.

Remember that these are nominal times, real manufactured parts have a bit of variation from unit to unit, but the charts and graphs should give you good starting point.